# jsGrid изменить ячейку программно

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как можно программно изменить значение ячейки jsGrid программно?
Задача в следующем - сейчас данные таблицы обновляются по таймеру с помощью loadData, однако в таблице меняются только некоторые ячейки. Хотелось бы без полной перезагрузки страницы обновить данные.

Comment: а вы документацию читали? http://js-grid.com/docs/#updateitemitemrowrownode-editeditem-promise , например, не подходит?

Comment: Спасибо за наводку. Проблема в том что я не нашел как получить item, который передается в $("#grid").jsGrid("updateItem", item, ....). Не нашел ни функций ни свойств для доступа к данным. Добавлю что загружаемых данных больше чем отображаемых для пользователя

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос какой-нибудь jsfiddle/SO snippet, чтобы можно было предметнее говорить. Я сам с jsGrid не работал, а писать что-то с нуля не хочется. Всяко будет больше желающих ответить

Answer (score 0):

сам спросил, сам отвечу.
не знаю на сколько корректно, но это работает.

```
 mydata = $("#jsGrid").jsGrid("option", "data");    
 $.each(mydata, function (index, value) {
    console.log(value);
    value["D_TYPE"]="999";
    $("#jsGrid").jsGrid("updateItem", value,value);
 });
```